# How to make two signs closer?

Tags: letterspacing

I use frequently combination of these two sings

1. · (used for word division)
2. | (used to show where endings join the word)

For example it frequently appears this combination ··| (·· main division + | ending).

In few exceptions I would need to put · and | closer. How to put those signs closer in exceptional situation?

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
 % normal
 hug·sjóna··|maður

 %closer
 hug·sjóna··|maður
\end{document}
```

Comment: `·\hspace{-1pt}| ` ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I use `\hspace{-0.06667em}` now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want a line break after a centered dot, so it makes sense using a penalty that can be later examined.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{·}{\chejnikcdot}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chejnikcdot}{%
  \ifnum\lastpenalty=10042
    \kern-0.06667em\relax % dots should always be kerned
  \fi
  \textperiodcentered
  \@ifnextchar|{\kern\chejnikkern\relax}{\penalty10042 }%
}

\newcommand{\closeupdotbar}{%
  \renewcommand\chejnikkern{-0.06667em}%
}
\newcommand\chejnikkern{0pt} % default


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
No kerning & hug\textperiodcentered sjóna\textperiodcentered\textperiodcentered|maður \\
Kerning & hug·sjóna··|maður \\
Kerning plus & \closeupdotbar hug·sjóna··|maður
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `\closeupdotbar` changes (locally) the kerning between a centered period and the vertical bar. In normal text you can do

```
{\closeupdotbar hug·sjóna··|maður}
```

for the special cases. Other interfaces are possible.

The `\chejnikdot` macro looks back: if it sees a penalty item with value 10042, it means that a centered dot has been typeset, so the macro applies a kern. Then it typesets the centered dot and issues the penalty that, besides being a signal, prohibits line breaks at the spot.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar,etoolbox}

\newif\ifclosersigns
\newunicodechar{·}{\advancedcdot}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\advancedcdot{\textperiodcentered
  \ifclosersigns\expandafter\@firstofone
  \else\expandafter\@gobble\fi{\@ifnextchar|{\hspace{-0.06667em}}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 % normal
 hug·sjóna··|maður

\closersignstrue

 %closer
 hug·sjóna··|maður
\end{document}
```

Addition to remove space from `··` and `·|` (not completely robust, but I think it's enough).

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar,etoolbox}

\newunicodechar{·}{\advancedcdot}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\advancedcdot{\textperiodcentered
  \@ifnextchar|{\hspace{-0.06667em}}{\checkifcdotnext}}
\newcommand*\checkifcdotnext[2]
  {\def\tmpa{·}\def\tmpb{#1#2}\ifx\tmpa\tmpb\hspace{-0.06667em}\fi#1#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 %closer
 hug·sjóna··|maður

\end{document}
```

A bit more robust would be

```
\newcommand*\advancedcdot{\textperiodcentered
  \@ifnextchar|{\hspace{-0.06667em}}{\@ifnextchar^^c2{\checkifcdotnext}{}}}
\newcommand*\checkifcdotnext[2]
  {\def\tmpa{·}\def\tmpb{#1#2}\ifx\tmpa\tmpb\hspace{-0.06667em}\fi#1#2}
```

Comment: Of course if you want to define the spacing globally it's easier. But I'm not sure if you wanted the two behaviours in the same document (since you said “normal” and “closer”).

Comment: Just to be completely sure, in combination `··|` it takes `-0.06667em` space between two middle dots + `-0.06667em` space between middle dot and `|` sign, right? * that is desired behaviour*

Comment: Yes, that's what this does.

Comment: I have decided to accept the Egreg's answer, because `\advanceddot` command have thrown an error later in code, precisely at `\multirow{5}{*}{ýmis\allowbreak ·}` part of code. I appreciate your answer as well, thank you very much.

Comment: With the last definition? The “a bit more robust would be” version.

Comment: No, with the not completely robust.

Comment: May be with the last version it does work :)